# Is there a positive integer $n$ where $14$ divide $30^n$? Explain why.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

The lecturer has not taught us proofs yet, so I think the question is not looking for a rigorous proof. My attempt:

$$30 = 2 \times 3 \times 5$$
$$\frac{30^n}{14} = \frac{2^n \times 3^n \times 5^n}{2 \times 7} = \frac{2^{n-1} \times 3^n \times 5^n}{7}$$

Now I have written this in prime numbers, which I presume will make it easier to solve.
I feel that $7$ is not going to divide any power of $2$, $3$, or $5$.
This is as close as I can get to a proof.

Comment: Yeah, it seems alright. Just take mod 7 on both sides and you're done.

Comment: The proof is absolutely valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is fine, but you don't have to actually divide $30^n$ by $14$. Just note that $30^n=2^n3^n5^n$ (which you did) and that therefore, since there is no $7$ here (and since $7$ is prime), $2^n3^n5^n$ is *not* a multiple of $7$. In particular, it is not a multiple of $14$.

Comment: My confusion is: How do we know $7$ cannot divide $2^n3^n$ or $2^n5^n$ $3^n5^n$, these combinations?

Comment: Because if a prime divides a product, it divides one of the factors. So, if $7\mid2^n3^n5^n$, then $7\mid2$, or $7\mid3$, or $7\mid5$. But this does not occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can also reason as follows:

- $30^n = (2\cdot 14 + 2)^n = m\cdot 14 + 2^n$ for a positive integer $m$
- It follows if $14 | 30^n$, then $14| 2^n$ which is **impossible** as $7$ is not a factor of any power $2^n$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$30^n\equiv 2,4,8\mod 14$$ so exists no such exponent for $$n\geq1 $$ and $$n\in\mathbb{N}$$